# Configure mysql, persistence.xml, JPA, SpringMVC

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-mvc, jpa

I was new in javaEE and creating a project using **Spring MVC using JPA and Mysql as database, Jboss as server**.
I was stuck in configuration, please find below the steps that I have followed

1: customerdiatatcher-servlet.xml  ( **Kept inside WebContent**)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd">

<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:jdbc.properties" />
<import resource="persistence.xml" />

<!-- Activates various annotations to be detected in bean classes -->
<context:annotation-config />

<!-- Scans the classpath for annotated components that will be auto-registered 
    as Spring beans. For example @Controller and @Service. Make sure to set the 
    correct base-package -->
<context:component-scan base-package="com.vivek" />

<!-- declare a view resolver property -->
<bean id="viewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>

<bean id="entityManagerFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean" />

<!-- Add Transaction support -->
<bean id="myTxManager"
    class="org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager" />

<!-- Use @Transaction annotations for managing transactions -->
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="myTxManager" />
```

2: Perisistence.xml ( **Kept inside ../META-INF/persistence.xml**)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><persistence version="2.0"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
<persistence-unit name="CustomerDetailsPU"
    transaction-type="JTA">
    <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
    <jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/jpa-datasource.xml</jta-data-source><class>com.vivek.model.Customer</class>
</persistence-unit></persistence>
```

3: created a datasource- jpa-datasource.xml (**inside WebContent**)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><datasources xmlns="http://www.jboss.org/ironjacamar/schema"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.jboss.org/ironjacamar/schema http://docs.jboss.org/ironjacamar/schema/datasources_1_0.xsd">
<!-- The datasource is bound into JNDI at this location. We reference this 
    in META-INF/persistence.xml -->
<datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/jpa-datasource.xml"
    pool-name="sample-pool" enabled="true" use-java-context="true" jta="true">
    <connection-url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/customerdb</connection-url>
     <driver-class>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driver-class>
    <driver>mysql</driver>
    <security>
        <user-name>root</user-name>
        <password>root</password>
    </security>
</datasource>
```

Problem is I don't know whether my approach is correct or not or my all files and there configurations are correct or not when I am deploying this server it shows me lots of errors. 
kindly check whether I have written a proper code in all my xmls or I am missing something.

Comment: Spring Boot solves this exact problem. Any issue in using it?

Comment: "lots of errors" ... so perhaps you may have wanted to mention what they are ...

Comment: IOException parsing XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/jpa-hibernate-example-servlet.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/jpa-hibernate-example-servlet.xml]

&

Could not open ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/jpa-hibernate-example-servlet.xml]